# OSX icon to open terminal to specific location

Tags: macos, unix

How would I create an icon that would open the terminal into a specific directory?  Could also be into the directory where the icon lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the easiest answer to this: use Finder services.  See http://www.howtogeek.com/210147/how-to-open-terminal-in-the-current-os-x-finder-location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Automator" this way:

1. Create an automator application
2. Add a "Run Script Applescript" action
3. Modify the code to:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
     tell application "terminal"
       activate
       set UnixPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
       do script with command "cd " & UnixPath
     end tell
   end run
   ```
4. Save it
5. Run it! Move it where you want, Run it...

Comment: That worked great.  Not sure what the "::" was supposed to do, but I removed it.

Comment: Sure it is probably not mandatory... '::' is the path separator for the older Macos syntax.